# Default values inside a message or srv definition

Tags: rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

elements in a srv or msg definition are assigned zero values by the default constructor. What about when I wish to assign a non-zero or other special value as the default initialization value to a msg element.

using a construct such as:

```
int32 x=100
```

regards x as a constant when the msg headers are generated.

Is what I'm looking for possible at all? Thanks much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27629/default-values-inside-a-message-or-srv-definition/) by [kbabu](https://answers.ros.org/users/453/kbabu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2012-02-14

Post score: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not in the message definition, itself. The problem is that message generation must support multiple languages.

For any specific language (like Python or C++), you can probably define your own derived class for the message with a constructor that fills in useful default values.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a feature in ROS1 but this is a feature in ROS2.
[Interface definition using .msg / .srv / .action files](https://design.ros2.org/articles/legacy_interface_definition.html)
Scroll down to the "Default values" section

In this ROS2 tutorial [Creating custom msg and srv files](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces.html)
They have you put the following in a .msg file

```
int64 num
```

By default the default value of a numerical datatype is 0. If you want to change the default value then put the desired default value after the name separated by a space. For example if you want to make the default value 1 then put the following in the .msg file.

```
int64 num 1
```

Now when you publish your message without defining the value of num it will publish num with a value of 1 instead of 0.

```
ros2 topic pub /numtopic tutorial_interfaces/msg/Num '{}'
```

You can confirm this by using ros2 topic echo.

```
ros2 topic echo /numtopic

num: 1
---
```

---

Originally posted by [Collin Hays](https://answers.ros.org/users/126253/collin-hays/) with karma: 11 on 2022-12-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1